# S3 Upload Where KEY != FILENAME (aws)

Tags: bash, curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'd like to use a unique identifier as my amazon s3 key, but still be able to download files under the original filename.

For instance, I'm uploading files using pre-signed POST. So let's say I'm posting using this curl string:

```
"curl -s -ss -X POST -i \
    -F \"key=my_files/1.format\" \
    -F \"AWSAccessKeyId=" + my_AWSAccessKeyId + "\" \
    -F \"Policy=" + my_policy + "\" \
    -F \"Signature=" + my_signature + "\" \
    -F \"file=@my_picture.jpg\" \
    https://my_bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/"
```

So I have this arbitrary file, "1.format" but it's really supposed to be my_picture.jpg. When I try to download from https://my_bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/my_files/1.format, I download the 1.format file, not the my_picture.jpg.

I know setting Content-Disposition is likely the right solution, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do that with curl correctly.

Comment: Content-Disposition needs to be set server side, don't think you can make curl do that, it's a response header

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set `Content-Disposition` header in `POST` request, that will be used in S3 responses. Just add `-H "Content-Disposition:whatever"` to `curl` call.

Another option is using `/` in key name and setting trailing part to original filename. E.g. `uuid/filename.jpeg`

Comment: When I try to set the -H "Content-Disposition=attachment;filename=RANDOMNAME.jpg", it doesn't actually save the file as RANDOMNAME.jpg when I try to download. Rather, it just uses the key name: 1.format.